# Where wordpress store $option_group information?

Tags: wordpress, setting

How are you.

Here is wordpress code for setting information.
I want to know in which table $option_group is stored?

For instance, when $option_group = "my_client_contact", in which table could I find "my_client_contact"?

```
<?php register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback ); ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group itself is not stored afaik. Option itself however is stored in `prefix_options` (`wp_options` by default) table, with whatever $option_name contains as a key. 
You can later retrieve it with `get_option('whatever $option_name contained')`